# Unable to connect to the Local Server with Integrated Security = True

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm unable to connect to the local SQL Server with

```
 connectionString="data source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security = True "
```

which gives the error message `"Login Failed for PCName\UserName"`

However, I am able to connect with this connection string

```
 connectionString="data source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User Id=sa;Password=abc;"
```

Why is it that I am unable to connect to the Local Server with Integrated Security = True?

I was under the impression that User Id and Password have to be specified for Remote connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you not have access rights to access local sql server under domain/windows account

Even if you installed the Sql Server you have to explicitly specify the accounts which have rights to connect to sql server and who will be sysadmin on this server except sa.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try below way:

If you are using SQLEXPRESS express then please in try way, thanks

```
data source=.SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security = True
```

**Update**
You might get your desired solution from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Elias. But Iam trying to connect to SQLServer 2005 instance not SqlServer

Comment: Hello @Ananth `Sql Server 2005`, you can look up your connection from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005 , thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which version of sql server you have, but run up sql server manager (or sql server enterprise if you are on 2000. You need to add the windows user and then choose which database(s) it can access. Integrated simply means you don't have to enter user name and password twice, not that windows users have access to everything.

When you find the option in the manager you'll see what it's doing.